# Using for loop to define multiple functions in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create 8 functions looking like `fcXX_at_this_z(r)`, where `XX` ranges from `47` to `54` in integer steps of 1.

So the first function shall have its protoype: `def fc47_at_this_z(r):`, the second function shall have its prototype `def fc48_at_this_z(r):` ... and the last function shall have its prototype `def fc54_at_this_z(r):`.

The body of these functions shall read:

```
return upgrade_interpolator_cXX(r)
```

where again XX ranges from 47 to 54.

So I need to be able to use the function name inside the body of the function, for each function.

How could I define these functions and their bodies using a for-loop in Python?

Moreover, I will need to use these functions, after I defined them, as following:

```
use_it(fc54_at_this_z, ...)
```

or

```
use_it(fc47_at_this_z, ...)
```

So again I need to be able to somehow insert that index 47, 48, ..., 54 inside that function call `use_it(f)`.

This would be my second question about these functions, how can I use in the way above, after I defined them using the for-loop?
Ideally, I need to use these inside a for loop, that is in pseudocode:

```
for idx in range(7):
    use_it(fc+(47+idx)+_at_this_z)
```

## The bigger picture

The bigger picture is as following:

I need to perform a 2Dim integral across z and r. The r limit is a function of z. So it's not a square, not a rectangle, it's a strange shape in 2Dims across which I need to integrate.
I partition the z using N_z as:

```
N_z = 10**3
z_is = (-zrange) + (np.arange(N_z) + 0.5) * (2.*zrange/N_z) # shall be shape(N_z,)
```

and perform adaptive gaussian integrals at each value of `z` from `z_is`. I store results in a matrix shaped `(N_z, 8)`.

The integrations at each value of `z` from `z_is` happen as:

```
results = np.zeros((N_z, 8))
errs = np.zeros((N_z,8))
for i in range(N_z):
# ideally a for loop with index idx shall appear here!
# that idx dictates which fcXX we work with. I need to work with all of them, so I need this additional for-loop to integrate all the fc_XX's across r, and store results in the matrices `results, err`
# now this code doesn't work, in particular the integrate_adaptive() below cannot populate the columns of the results and errs matrices!
# it doesn't know understand the 2nd dimension of the results matrices, it just integrates f_c54, rather than all the f_cXX's!
    def fc54_at_this_z(r): # depenedent only on r
        I_to_query_at = get_I_at_this_z_and_r(z_is[i], r)
        return (2 * pi * r * interpolator_c54(I_to_query_at))
    r_thresh_of_z = get_r_thr(z_is[i])
    results[i, idx], errs[i, idx] = quadpy.c1.integrate_adaptive(fc54_at_this_z, [0., r_thresh_of_z ])
```

Comment: Any reason that you aren't creating a single function `fc(XX,r)`, or perhaps a dictionary of functions called like `fc[XX](r)`?

Comment: It is interesting to think on creating functions during excecution, but I'm pretty sure you can write your program without doing this (as mentioned by @JohnColeman )

Comment: The situation is more complex than in the q. The problem in the q stops me from doing 8 adaptive gaussian integrals across radius r with 8 different 
integrands. The integrand is dependent on that XX. The integration routine accepts as input the integrand (that is, use_it function needs to take in the integrand name).

Comment: You can create a function factory, a higher-order function that takes `XX` as input and returns the function for output. The result can be stored in a dictionary and then used as needed. Python can create functions dynamically, but it isn't natural to do so with *named* functions.

Comment: It's still unclear why you need to define those as separate functions instead of passing a callback function with (pre-bound) parameters. Are you saying `use_it` looks at the *name of the function* to derive something from it? Short of that, there's no reason for doing this. Even if `use_it` would be doing that, you can probably duck punch the name of the function instead of defining functions dynamically.

Comment: I will update the question to explain in short what I want to achieve, and if you have time, maybe you tell me a better way to do it, because this is the only solution I could think of, given that I am a Physicist without much programming experience.

Comment: Yes, currently this sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)…

Comment: Anything useful now towards the end of the Q, where I added some details?

Comment: @JohnColeman eh, it's perfectly fine to do this with a function definition statement.

Comment: Doesn't this go one layer deeper to `interpolator_c54` as well? Are those dynamically defined as well somehow…?

Comment: the interpolators , interpolator_c54, interpolator_c53, etc., are defined by reading from a .npy file saved in the current folder, as c54_interp = np.load('interpolator_c54.npy', allow_pickle=True) then writing
interpolator_c54 = c54_interp.item() , and basically doing this manually 8 times at the beginning of the code

Comment: The fundamental problem with your approach is you are putting *data* into your variable names. Don't do that.

Comment: Well, consider using dicts for those, like `interpolators[54] = ...`, and pass `54` through as a variable to access `interpolators[n]` as needed.

Comment: Problem solved for interpolators being read from a file, now all in a dictionary. Is there a simple way to go about the actual interpolators I was using, upgraded versions of the ones read from the files, as in here : def upgrade_interpolator_c53(I):
    if np.amin(I) <= (10** 20) or np.amax(I) >= (10** 25):
        return 0.
    else:
        return inter53(I)       . The trick with for i in range(7): new_dict[i+47] = ... is not that easy anymore when wanting to store functions with their bodies inside the dict

Comment: `def upgrade_interpolator(l, i): ... return interpolators[i](l)`, then call it as `upgrade_interpolator(..., 53)`. If you need to pass that around, pass `lambda l: upgrade_interpolator(l, 53)`.

Comment: Thanks! Are your three dots ... my np. comparisons instructions? I am sorry, but how do I use the function you posted to upgrade the functionality of each of the interpolators from the interpolators dictionary? Do I call: upgrade_interpolator(..., i+47) for i in range(8)? What do you mean by ''if you need to pass that around'' ? If I want to use inter53 object (say) from my previous comment, do I need to write upgrade_interpolator(I, 53) for querying the 53 interpolator at 1 specific value of Intensity equal to I?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using a template:

```
fc_template = 'def fc{0}_at_this_z(r): return upgrade_interpolator_c{0}(r)'
for i in range(47, 55):
    exec(f_template.format(i))
```

You can define different templates that suite your needs, depending on what exactly you're trying to do. As other users noted in the comments, dynamically creating named functions is not necessarily a good idea, so be careful.

If you need a function defined over multiple lines you can do this:

```
fc_template = """
def fc{0}_at_this_z(r):
    return upgrade_interpolator_c{0}(r)
"""
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, what if the function does 3 instructions, rather than 1 (the return in your answer) ?

Comment: @velenos14 then you can create a more complex tempate

Comment: I'm sorry but probably it's a dumb question, but in particular, how shall I input the instructions? I mean there's no ; as in C++ in Python, to make the template aware that a new instruction needs to be executed. Can you please just add 1 or 2 new more instructions, print("instr1") and print("instr2") in your template please, while leaving the return statement in the last place?

Comment: @velenos14 do not do it this way. Using `exec` is *completely unnecessary*. Just use a factory function, and store the resulting functions in some container, like a `dict`

Comment: @velenos14 see my updated answer. But again, while my answer provides a way to achieve exactly what you are trying to do, the way you are trying to do things is not the best one, you should listen to advice given by other users :)