# How to upgrade the behaviour of functions and store the new ones in a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation, numerical-methods

I have a dictionary `interpolators` with keys from 47 to 54 in integer steps and values items read from files:

```
interpolators = dict()

for i in range(7):
    interpolators[i+47] = np.load('interpolator_c{}.npy'.format(i+47), allow_pickle=True).item()
```

I want to create 8 functions, 1 for each of the XX keys, where XX is from 47 to 54 as above, and store these functions inside a dictionary to later use them as: `new_dict[i](x) for i in range(8)`, if these 8 functions are stored in the dictionary `new_dict` .
The functions shall all aim to upgrade the functionality of the interpolators. In particular, if these interpolators are queried outside their range, an error appears, and I want to circumvent this manually and obtain upgraded interpolators which respond accordingly in all situations.

My try was to write this:

```
def upgrade_interpolator(I,i):
    if np.amin(I) <= (10**20) or np.amax(I) >= (10**25):
        return 0.
    else:
        return interpolators[i](I)
```

and to call it as:

```
for i in range(8):
    interpolators[i+47] = upgrade_interpolators(..., i+47)
```

But this fails because `if np.amin(I) <= (10**20) or np.amax(I) >= (10**25): TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'ellipsis' and 'int'`

How can I get 8 functions which when queried at `I`'s outside the bounds, respond accordingly returning 0., while when queried inside the bounds, respond by querying the `interpolators` dictionary at the required key, accessing that object and querying it at that `I`?

Thank you!

---

---

### Update:

I did it this way:

```
def make_upgraded_interpolators(XX):
    if XX!=54:
        def interpolator_upgraded(I):
            if np.argmin(I) <= (10**20) or np.argmax(I) >= (10**25):
                return 0
            else:
                return interpolators[XX](I)
        return interpolator_upgraded

    else:
        def interpolator_upgraded_c54(I):
            if np.argmin(I) <= (10**20):
                return 0.
            else:
                if np.argmin(I) >= (10**25):
                    return 1.
                else:
                    return interpolators[54](I)
        return interpolator_upgraded_c54
# use it!
dict_interpolators_upgraded = dict()
for i in range(8):
    dict_interpolators_upgraded[i+47] = make_upgraded_interpolators(i+47)
```

I do get an error when writing and here someone who knows `scipy.integrate` or `quadpy` maybe can help me:

```
results = np.zeros((N_z, 8))
errs = np.zeros((N_z,8))

for i in range(N_z): # for all z-values

    def make_fcXXs(XX):
        def funct(r):
            I_to_query_at = get_I_at_this_z_and_r(z_is[i], r)
            return 2 * pi * r * dict_interpolators_upgraded[XX+47](I_to_query_at/(10**4))
        return funct
    # use it!
    fcXX = dict()
    for j in range(8):
        fcXX[j+47] = make_fcXXs(j+47)
    r_thres_of_z_i = get_r_thr(z_is[i])
    for idx in range(8): # for all c_XX's
        results[i, idx], errs[i, idx] = scipy.integrate.quad(fcXX[idx+47], 0., r_thres_of_z_i, epsabs=1.0e-20, epsrel=1.0e-1)

## The error reads ##
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "integration_RRon_scipyquad_version.py", line 104, in <module>
    results[i, idx], errs[i, idx] = scipy.integrate.quad(fcXX[idx+47], 0., r_thres_of_z_i, epsabs=1.0e-20, epsrel=1.0e-1)
  File "/home/velenos14/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 351, in quad
    retval = _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit,
  File "/home/velenos14/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 463, in _quad
    return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
  File "integration_RRon_scipyquad_version.py", line 91, in funct
    return 2 * pi * r * dict_interpolators_upgraded[XX+47](I_to_query_at/(10**4))
KeyError: 94
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, maybe you can add a `try ... except` block and when it gets a TypeError, you return 0, otherwise, returns `interpolators[i](I)`?

Comment: What is `upgrade_interpolators(..., i+47)` supposed to mean?  '...' is an `ellipsis` object.  It's normally only used in `numpy` array indexing.

Comment: This is what a programmer from SO told me to do, but I didn't quite understand the mechanics behind this instruction. I have thought that three dots signify that I don't want to input the I argument.   I believe I eventually managed to achieve my aim in another way. Please, can you look at the updated q and see if I did it right, in a correct way from the point of view of a programmer? I do get another error, but further down the code.

Comment: Do you mean deceze [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66967035/using-for-loop-to-define-multiple-functions-in-python#comment118374313_66967035)? They meant "fill in something appropriate here", not "literally stick an ellipsis in your code".

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, OK, yes, it is from there. I thought I did it somehow, but I get another error down the code which might be due to my method to store these functions inside a dictionary. Can you please have a quick look and see if you notice any obvious mistake?

Comment: You seem to have lost track of which part of your code is responsible for adding 47. That `94` comes from adding 47 twice.

Comment: The `KeyError` is in the `dict_interpolators_upgraded[XX+47]` expression.  It has nothing to do with `quad`.

Comment: thank you! I corrected it and the code works now!